# Incorrect rendering experience when using canvas. Canvas

Tags: javascript, node.js, canvas, discord.js

I am trying to render experience using canvas, well when I render experience it goes out of scope.
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B7Iwu.png)

```
    const exp = users.xp;

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.lineWidth - 4;
    ctx.strokeStyle = '#ffffff';
    ctx.globalAlpha = 0.2;
    ctx.fillStyle = '#433F99';
    ctx.fillRect(253 + 18.5, 130, 420, 45);
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.globalAlpha = 1;
    ctx.strokeRect(253 + 18.5, 130, 420, 45);
    ctx.stroke();

    ctx.fillStyle - '#3F9946';
    ctx.globalAlpha = 0.6;
    ctx.fillRect(253 + 18.5, 130, exp, 45);
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.globalAlpha = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You're just plugging `exp` directly into the `width` argument when filling the rectangle. It seems like `exp` is greater than `420` (the width of the experience bar) so it fills outside of the bar.

You need to define a maximum - at what experience amount should the bar be full?
Then you need a behavior for what happens when the user gets *more* experience than that maximum - if that is possible. Does the bar restart? Does it just cap out and not show anything past?

Here's an example with a max-experience of 500 and the bar capping at the max.

```
let width = (exp / 500) * 420; //convert exp to "percent to full", then convert to width
ctx.fillRect(253 + 18.5, 130, Math.min(width, 420), 45); //if width > 420, cap at 420
```

**Edit:** If your experience system has a "total experience" and the user reaches certain levels at experience milestones, you just need to obtain a percentage progress from the last level to the next level.

So, for example:

```
let exp = 1450; //sample value
let levels = [100, 500, 1000, 2000, 4000]; //some example levels

//get current level somehow - in this case with an array of exp thresholds, this will work
let currentLevel = levels.findIndex(l => exp < l) - 1; // = 2
let expTowardsNextLevel = exp - levels[currentLevel]; // = 450
let percentProgress = expTowardsNextLevel / (levels[currentLevel+1] - levels[currentLevel]);
ctx.fillRect(253 + 18.5, 130, Math.min(width, 1) * 420, 45);
```

Comment: I am trying to get the scale to display an approximate percentage to the next level, how can this be implemented with the values ​​of the current experience and the amount of experience to the next level?

Comment: @Easygoing Simply put "the amount of experience to the next level" in where the 500 is currently. Depending on how your experience system was implemented you may also need the amount of experience that was needed for the previous level. I'll edit my answer.